# Python urllib2 does not respect timeout

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

The following two lines of code hangs forever:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen('https://www.5giay.vn/', timeout=5)
```

This is with python2.7, and I have no http_proxy or any other env variables set. Any other website works fine. I can also wget the site without any issue. What could be the issue?

Comment: I see this on both Linux (Amazon AMI) and Mac OS. Also, doesn't seem related to DNS, because even this hangs: urllib2.urlopen('https://210.245.123.158', timeout=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run

```
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.5giay.vn/'
urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=1.0)
```

wait for a few seconds, and then use C-c to interrupt the program, you'll see

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

This shows that the program is hanging on `self._sslobj.read(len)`.

[SSL timeouts raise `socket.timeout`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/3d9a86b8cc98/).

You can control the delay before socket.timeout is raised by calling
`socket.setdefaulttimeout(1.0)`.

For example,

```
import urllib2
import socket

socket.setdefaulttimeout(1.0)
url = 'https://www.5giay.vn/'
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=1.0)
except IOError as err:
    print('timeout')
```

---

```
% time script.py
timeout

real    0m3.629s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.024s
```

---

Note that [the requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) succeeds here although `urllib2` did not:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.5giay.vn/')
```

---

**How to enforce a timeout on the entire function call:**

`socket.setdefaulttimeout` only affects how long Python waits before an exception is raised *if the server has not issued a response*.

Neither it nor `urlopen(..., timeout=...)` enforce a time limit on the entire function call.

To do that, you could use eventlets, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21965484/190597).

If you don't want to install `eventlets`, you could use `multiprocessing` from the standard library; though this solution will not scale as well as an asynchronous solution such as the one `eventlets` provides.

```
import urllib2
import socket
import multiprocessing as mp

def timeout(t, cmd, *args, **kwds):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    result = pool.apply_async(cmd, args=args, kwds=kwds)
    try:
        retval = result.get(timeout=t)
    except mp.TimeoutError as err:
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()
        raise
    else:
        return retval

def open(url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print(response)

url = 'https://www.5giay.vn/'
try:
    timeout(5, open, url)
except mp.TimeoutError as err:
    print('timeout')
```

Running this will either succeed or timeout in about 5 seconds of wall clock time.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. With a timeout of 1, it does time out. But if you make the timeout=5.0, it hangs forever. Strange!

Comment: Thanks, in this case the webserver was misconfigured, sending 1 character every second. So the timeout was not hitting, and still the request will take forever.