# Python Timeout doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have the following code;

```
def ip_addresses():
    # Get external ipv4
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://icanhazip.com', timeout = 2)
        out = response.read()
        public_ipv4 = re.sub('\n', '', out)
    except:
        public_ipv4 = "failed to retrieve public_ipv4"
```

In normal circumstance, when response from http://icanhazip.com is received, the output is something like this;

```
xxx@xxx:/var/log$ date && tail -1 xxx.log
Tue Jul 25 **07:43**:18 UTC 2017  {"public_ipv4": "208.185.193.131"}, "date": "2017-07-25 **07:43**:01.558242"
```

So, the current date and the date of the log generation are same.
However, when there is an exception, this is happening;

```
xxx@xxx:/var/log$ date && tail -1 xxx.log
Tue Jul 25 **07:30**:25 UTC 2017  {"public_ipv4": "failed to retrieve public_ipv4"},"date": "2017-07-25 **07:23**:01.525444"
```

Why is the "timeout" not working?

Comment: is that `date && tail -1 xxx.log` run automatically? Because otherwise the time difference is somewhat irrelevant

Comment: You could log the exception to see what's going on: `except Exception as err:` and `public_ipv4 = "failed to retrieve public_ipv4; reason: " + str(err)`

Comment: @dhdavvie: The date & tail was run manually to check the timestamp. If the time difference is more than 5 minutes, it causes an alert in "Splunk" to where these logs are fed to.

Comment: @VPfB: Ok will try that out. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python urllib2 does not respect timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327787/python-urllib2-does-not-respect-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the verbose exception details in this manner 
and then investigate what is the error all about, the difference in time 
Use this format...

```
import sys
try:
    1 / 0
except:
    print sys.exc_info()
```