# Bug in python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I have some `raspberry pi` running some `python` code.  Once and a while my devices will fail to check in.  The rest of the python code continues to run perfectly but the code here quits.  I am not sure why?  If the devices can't check in they should reboot but they don't.  Other threads in the `python` file continue to run correctly.

```
class reportStatus(Thread):
    def run(self):
        checkInCount = 0
        while 1:
            try:
                if checkInCount < 50:
                    payload = {'d':device,'k':cKey}
                    resp = requests.post(url+'c', json=payload)
                    if resp.status_code == 200:
                        checkInCount = 0
                        time.sleep(1800) #1800
                    else:
                        checkInCount += 1
                        time.sleep(300) # 2.5 min
                else:
                    os.system("sudo reboot")
            except:
                try:
                    checkInCount += 1
                    time.sleep(300)
                except:
                    pass
```

The devices can run for days and weeks and will check in perfectly every 30 minutes, then out of the blue they will stop.  My `linux` computers are in read-only and the computer continue to work and run correctly.  My issue is in this thread.  I think they might fail to get a response and this line could be the issue

```
resp = requests.post(url+'c', json=payload)
```

I am not sure how to solve this, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: Do you have any traceback at all? I wouldn't say that requests is the issue, since there is a "catch all" exception after it

Comment: The copy paste caused the indentation error, it is correct inn the python file.

Comment: well, can't help you unless you make it correct here too....

Comment: You say "If the devices can't check in they should reboot but they don't". Did you actually wait 50 * 300 seconds (which is more than 4 hours) after they get out of sync? BTW, you're only checking the response status code, but not the content, maybe it's a good idea to log what the actual response is.

Comment: Yes  I have waited.  The device never reboots or checks in again but other threads continue to work correctly.  Once I manually reboot the device it checks in again correctly.  I don't understand why my question was down voted.  I have done tons of research,  There is a try, except,,, the thread should run forever.   I don't understand what I am missing...

Comment: I would recommend you don't just swallow every possible exception since it could very much be relevent to the issue.  just call `traceback.print_exc()` inside the `except` block to see what went wrong.  For one it is possible that when it tries to reboot the `SystemExit` that stops the python process is just being caught stopping the reboot.

Comment: I suggest you simplify your script to check that the `os.system('sudo reboot')` line works as expected.

Comment: os.system('sudo reboot') does work as expected.  If I modify time.sleep(1) instead of 300 and checkInCount < 5 instead of 50 and then disconnect the internet source the device does reboot after a minute or two.  The rebooting will continue until I reconnect the internet source and then the device checks in.  I do appreciate the suggestion and help from everyone.  Thank you

Comment: if `sudo` prompts for password, the invoking thread will block until `sudo` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bare [`except:pass` is a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553825/3579910).

A much better approach would be to, at the very minimum, log any exceptions:

```
import traceback

while True:
  try:
    time.sleep(60)
  except:
    with open("exceptions.log", "a") as log:
      log.write("%s: Exception occurred:\n" % datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
      traceback.print_exc(file=log)
```

Then, when you get an exception, you get a log:

```
2016-12-20 13:28:55: Exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sleepy.py", line 8, in <module>
    time.sleep(60)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

It is also possible that your code is hanging on [`sudo reboot`](https://askubuntu.com/a/155827/565455) or [`requests.post`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts). You could add additional logging to troubleshoot which issue you have, although given you've seen it do reboots, I suspect it's `requests.post`, in which case you need to add a [timeout (from the linked answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22096841/3579910):

```
import requests
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()


#...
resp = None
with eventlet.Timeout(10):
    resp = requests.post(url+'c', json=payload)
if resp:
    # your code
```

Comment: I am positive the code is not hanging on sudo reboot.  Great answer!  Thank you!  I am certain requsts.post is not getting a response occasionally  and waiting for ever.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically ignores *all* exceptions. This is considered a bad thing in Python.

The only reason I can think of for the behavior that you're seeing is that after `checkInCount` reaches 50, the `sudo reboot` raises an exception which is then ignored by your program, keeping this thread stuck in the infinite loop.

If you want to see what really happens, add `print` or `loggging.info` statements to all the different branches of your code.

Alternatively, remove the blanket try-except clause or replace it by something specific, e.g. `except requests.exceptions.RequestException`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the answers given I was able to come up with a solution.  I realized requests has a built in time out function.  The timeout will never happen if a timeout is not specified as a parameter.
here is my solution:

```
resp = requests.post(url+'c', json=payload, timeout=45)
```

> You can tell Requests to stop waiting for a response after a given
>   number of seconds with the timeout parameter. Nearly all production
>   code should use this parameter in nearly all requests. Failure to do
>   so can cause your program to hang indefinitely

The answers provided by TemporalWolf and other helped me alot.  Thank you to all that helped.

Comment: The built-in timeout helps, but does not prevent hanging - it's the maximum wait *between* server communications, not the maximum time for the call to return.

Comment: OK.  I will use eventlet.