# Python3 requests.get is too slow

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

**EDIT** Adding info:

***requests*** version: 2.21.0

***Server info:*** a Windows python implementation which includes 10 instances of ***threading.Thread***, each creating ***HTTPServer*** with a handler based on ***BaseHTTPRequestHandler***. My do_GET looks like this:

```
def do_GET(self):
    rc = 'some response'
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(rc.encode('utf-8'))
```

I'm getting a strange behaviour.

***Using the `curl` command line***, the GET command is ***finished quickly:***

`curl "http://localhost:3020/pbio/button2?cmd=uz-crosslink-leds&g1=0&g2=0&g3=0&g4=1&tmr=1"`

***However***, using `requests.get()` of python ***takes too much time***. I was isolated it up to

`python -c "import requests; requests.get('http://localhost:3020/pbio/button2?cmd=uz-crosslink-leds&g1=0&g2=0&g3=0&g4=1&tmr=1')"`

I scanned through many other questions here and have tried many things, without success.

Here are some of my findings:

- If I'm adding `timeout=0.2`, the call is ending quickly without any error.
- However, adding `timeout=5` or timeout=(5,5)` doesn't make it take longer. It always seem to be waiting **a full one second** before returning with results.
- Working with a session wrapper, and cancelling keep-alive, didn't improve. I mean for this:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update({'Connection': 'close'})
    url = "http://localhost:3020/pbio/button2?cmd=uz-crosslink-leds&g1=0&g2=0&g3=0&g4=%d&tmr=0" % i
    session.get(url, timeout=2)
```

- Enabling full debug, I'm getting the following output:

```
url=http://localhost:3020/pbio/button2?cmd=uz-crosslink-leds&g1=0&g2=0&g3=0&g4=1&tmr=0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:3020
send: b'GET /pbio/button2?cmd=uz-crosslink-leds&g1=0&g2=0&g3=0&g4=1&tmr=0 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:3020\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.7.2
header: Date: Wed, 01 May 2019 15:28:29 GMT
header: Content-type: text/html
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:3020 "GET /pbio/button2?cmd=uz-crosslink-leds&g1=0&g2=0&g3=0&g4=1&tmr=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
url=http://localhost:3020/pbio/powermtr?cmd=read-power-density
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: localhost
slight pause here
send: b'GET /pbio/powermtr?cmd=read-power-density HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:3020\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.7.2
header: Date: Wed, 01 May 2019 15:28:30 GMT
header: Content-type: text/html
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:3020 "GET /pbio/powermtr?cmd=read-power-density HTTP/1.1" 200 None
6.710,i=4
url=http://localhost:3020/pbio/button2?cmd=uz-crosslink-leds&g1=0&g2=0&g3=0&g4=4&tmr=0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: localhost
slight pause here
...
```

Comment: requests version

Comment: What server is this connecting to? Have you got any performance metrics for that setup? If you replaced `http://localhost:3020/pbio/button2` with `http://httpbin.org/get` do you see the same differences in performance?

Comment: I might overlook something obvious here but your python debug does **two** get requests when your curl would obviously only make one. For further troubleshooting, you can also do `curl -v "http://localhost:3020/pbio/button2?cmd=uz-crosslink-leds&g1=0&g2=0&g3=0&g4=1&tmr=1"` then cross check the get request of the curl and the get request of python matches

Comment: Another point of note: `curl` can't keep connections open, because it makes one request per process. So a badly behaving server that keeps connections open then drops them after a timeout will not faze `curl` as it has already closed the connection out of necessity.

Comment: Finally: `Connection: close` is a HTTP/1.1 header, but the server you are connecting to states it implements HTTP/1.0. It is the server's responsibility to close the socket properly, clearly it is not doing so here.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I did provide some more info. The server is a standard Python server and I didn't find anything I need to do in order to close the request. My `do_GET()` is ending with `self.wfile.write(rc.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: If at all possible, maybe try a more modern server library like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) **(Hello World is 6 lines)**

Comment: I think that you should write `session.verify = True` to ignore the session verification if it's a live or not

Comment: Hi @NejiSoltani, it doesn't make any change.

Comment: @ishahak my bad, I meant `session.verify = False`

Comment: Hi @NejiSoltani, I was suspecting that myself. Still no change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It took me 3 years to find an answer.
I still do not understand why, but at least I can suggest a working solution.

According to [these docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts), the timeout can be specified as a tuple, like this:

```
(timeout for connection, timeout for interval without data)
```

Although I **do not understand** why *requests* is waiting for [timeout] **before issuing the connection**, I can tell it to wait very little for the *connection*, and specify another timeout for the data.

So what I'm doing now, is giving a timeout of let's say `(0.01, 4)`. Now the connection is immediate, and if the data has a deadtime of 4 seconds, it will generate a timeout exception.

Some interesting reading can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965484/timeout-for-python-requests-get-entire-response).

Hoping this info will help others!

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts):

> timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather, an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the underlying socket for timeout seconds). **If no timeout is specified explicitly, requests do not time out.**