# Python API simple requests.get throwing error

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

I'm going through the below tutorial and trying to execute the same commands @ 24:45, but getting an error. What would be the issue?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbLc5a9jdXo

Commands I'm running are as below. I'm running this on Jupyter notebook with Anaconda.
If I enter that link in Chrome I can see the JSON data

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")



**Error as below** 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    158             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 159                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    160 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     79     if err is not None:
---> 80         raise err
     81 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     69                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 70             sock.connect(sa)
     71             return sock

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    342         try:
--> 343             self._validate_conn(conn)
    344         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    838         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 839             conn.connect()
    840 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    300         # Add certificate verification
--> 301         conn = self._new_conn()
    302         hostname = self.host

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    167             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 168                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    169 

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023BB5434B48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    398         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 399             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    400 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.stackexchange.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023BB5434B48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4db0c3b4a994> in <module>
----> 1 response = requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.stackexchange.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023BB5434B48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Comment: use `print(response.json())` to see the json data

Comment: code is failing at third line, so no object with response is created

below is the error I get 

----> 1 print(response.json())

NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Comment: check your network, or try it in python interpreter in terminal/Konsole, (it is working fine for me )

Comment: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" - maybe the site doesn't like you. Are you doing web scraping on api.stackexchange.com? Perhaps you've made too many requests in too short a timespan.

Comment: This error is showing up from the first run onwards

Comment: same error from terminal also

Answer (score 0):

I think adding timeout might help. Try doing:
`requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow", timeout=10)`

Note: timeout used here is in seconds

If that doesn't help then refer to this question for more help. [Timeout for python requests.get entire response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965484/timeout-for-python-requests-get-entire-response)

Comment: getting timeout error now, I also tried to put 200 as timeout 

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Try some different link. See if this gives any errors https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1