# Python requests module getting stuck for long time even if the timeout is provided

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a call to an amazon page for web scraping. But even with timeout_connect and timeout_response provided, some of the threads get stuck for hours sometimes.
Snippet is below:

```
timeout_connect = 10
timeout_respose_factor = 20

r = requests.get(url,
                 headers=headers,
                 timeout=(timeout_connect, timeout_response),
                 verify=False)
```

It does timeout for some requests when it reaches this threshold and is not able to connect. But for a very few requests, some threads get stuck as it takes hours for requests to respond.

Am I missing something here? And if this might happen, is there a way I can keep track of this requests call in that thread and if its more than a particular time, I will just move forward, instead of waiting for requests?

Comment: This might be a bug (maybe try the latest version) or the server does not like you and sends you one byte every 10s. I'd try to sniff such connection to check. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22096841/15862) for a work-around.

Comment: @Tometzky, any leads on how to check such a connection ?