# Running the code gives "upstream request timeout", where me Iris data set has around 300,000 lines of data and I my rest api is from Azure cloud

Tags: python, mlops

I have even tried reducing the length of data, but it's not working

```
import requests
import time
import json

with open("Iris.csv") as f:
line = f.readline()
headers = line.strip().split(",")
features = []
for l in f.readlines():
features.append(list(map(lambda x: float(x), l.strip().split(",")\[1:-1\])))
models = ["onnx","pmml","pfa"]

for _ in range(600):
data1 = requests.post("https://axscdfd/score", json={
        "models": models,
        "x": features,
         }, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer abcdefght"}, timeout=(100,100))
print(data1.content)
time.sleep(2)
```

I tried running this code, and am expecting it to upload the data and print {}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What do you mean by "it's not working"?  What is your actual output?   What is the full traceback error?  Please also format your code properly.

Comment: I couldnt get output, even if its running.It is not an error actually, But I dont know how to fix this issue. It should actually print b'{}'. but it is printing b'upstream request timeout'

Comment: Well, 'upstream time out' tends to be an issue with the server not responding in time.  Perhaps take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965484/timeout-for-python-requests-get-entire-response